# How to make jQuery objects from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, namespaces

```
anArray = ['thing1','thing2','thing3'];
$.each(anArray, function (i,el) {
   var object = 'name.space.' + el;
   var selector = 'node-' + el;
   var object = $('#' + selector);//need object here to be interpreted as it's value
       //as if: var name.space.thing1 = $('#' + selector);
});
```

such that these are usable jQuery objects:

```
console.log(name.space.thing1);
console.log(name.space.thing2);
console.log(name.space.thing3);
```

I feel like eval() is involved. I'm hydrating navigation selectors so as pages are added/removed, we just update the array. We could build the array from the nav nodes, but either way, we still need to be able to make these namespaced selectors...

Comment: what are you attempting to accomplish? there has to be a better way.

Comment: Numbers aren't valid at the start of a javascript variable name. So your format won't work.

Comment: I want cached jQuery objects of navigation nodes in the dom. Prefer the creation of these objects to be tied to iterating across an array, or over the nav nodes themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use bracket notation:

```
var array = ['thing1', 'thing2'];
var object = {};
object.space = {};
$.each(array, function () {
    object.space[this] = $('#node-' + this);
});

console.log(object.space.thing1); // [<div id="node-1">];
```

Comment: Feels like this and the answer bazmegakapa [gave] are the same. I can't select an answer yet either way. Which do I choose? Allow folks to vote more?

Comment: Feel free to vote for either one, I guess it's customary to select the oldest answer. But it doesn't matter, vote for both. Mark one answered. The world continues :)

Comment: Yeah, no worries either way I guess :).

Comment: Thanks for the help folks! I couldn't upvote as I don't have enough rep yet. I know, I know. I'm not late in the real world, here I am.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish, but

```
name.space[el] = $('#' + selector);
```

might work.

Object properties are always accessible with the bracket notation as well. This means that `obj.xy` is just the same as `obj['xy']`, but the latter is more flexible and can be used in situations like yours.

Comment: This seems to work. Though, I'm not clear on how name.space[el] is reference-able later as name.space.thing1. Where's that . coming from? Is that part of []?

Comment: @folktrash - `name.space["thing1"]` is equivalent to `name.space.thing1` in JavaScript.  Since `el === "thing1"` then `name.space[el] === name.space["thing1"] === name.space.thing1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var anArray = ['thing1','thing2','thing3'];
var name    = {space:new Array()};

$.each(anArray, function (i,el) {
   var selector = 'node-' + el;
   name.space[el] = $('#' + selector);
});
```